# Not response webservice. Not found valid certification

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport

We are developing an application in java and since a few weeks ago we have a problem that we are not able to solve. It is a call to a webservice to obtain a series of data with certificates. We have followed the following steps for the creation of the artifacts and the subsequent call

1.We launch the wsimport command in the windows cmd wsimport -keep https: //xxx/xxx/xxx.svc? SingleWsdl -s C: \ Users \ mvelasco \ Documents \ xx \ xxxx \ src \ main \ java -Xauthfile C: \ Users \ mvelasco \ authwsdl.txt It generates a series of classes with the structures of the ws and the datacontract.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUGBy.jpg)

2. We have imported the certificates

keytool -importcert -keystore "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file -alias x

3. We have created a class with the following ws call method

   private static void llamadaAlServicio() {
       IDocumentosService port = (new DocumentosService())
               .getBasicHttpBindingIDocumentosService();
       BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) port;
       log.error("Username: "+ContextProperties.getAsiturWsUsuario());
       log.error("Password: "  +ContextProperties.getAsiturWsPassword());

   ```
   prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,
           ContextProperties.getAsiturWsUsuario());
   prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,
           ContextProperties.getAsiturWsPassword());

   ArrayOfAttachmentDTO arrAttachmentDTO = port
               .getAllAttachments("1234567");
   ```

   }

The DocumentosService class is generated by JAX-WS

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "DocumentosService", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", wsdlLocation = "https://xxx/xxx/xxx.svc?singleWsdl") public class DocumentosService extends Service {

private final static URL DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
private final static WebServiceException DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
private final static QName DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "DocumentosService");

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://xxx/xxx/xxx.svc?singleWsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
}

public DocumentosService() {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public DocumentosService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public DocumentosService(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public DocumentosService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public DocumentosService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public DocumentosService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns IDocumentosService
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentosService")
public IDocumentosService getBasicHttpBindingIDocumentosService() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentosService"), IDocumentosService.class);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param features
 *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
 * @return
 *     returns IDocumentosService
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentosService")
public IDocumentosService getBasicHttpBindingIDocumentosService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentosService"), IDocumentosService.class, features);
}

private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
    if (DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
        throw DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    }
    return DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
}
```

4. The PROBLEM is that from our machines in local windows we get the ws to respond correctly with this implementation. However, when we went into pre-production environments under Linux, we could not connect. The trace that appears is the following

> ```
> 2018-02-21 18:35:15,614 [Thread-22] [ WARN] (com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wspolicy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector:255) ->
> ```
>
> WSP0075: Policy assertion
>   "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http}BasicAuthentication"
>   was evaluated as "UNKNOWN". 2018-02-21 18:35:15,615 [Thread-22] [
>   WARN]
>   (com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wspolicy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector:255) ->
>   WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side
>   with fitness "UNKNOWN". 2018-02-21 18:35:15,666 [Thread-22] [ERROR]
>   (com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil:116) ->
>   Usernamejavax.xml.ws.security.auth.username 2018-02-21 18:35:15,667
>   [Thread-22] [ERROR] (com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil:117)
>   -> Passwordjavax.xml.ws.security.auth.password 2018-02-21 18:35:15,667 [Thread-22] [ERROR] (com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil:44) ->
>   Llamada al servicio GetAttachment con los datos: 593718000029818
>   2018-02-21 18:35:15,741 [Thread-22] [ERROR]
>   (com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil:63) -> HTTP transport
>   error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target 2018-02-21
>   18:35:15,742 [Thread-22] [ERROR]
>   (com.noaris.agis.screens.expedientes.DetalleExpediente_DocumentacionVM:1040)
>   -> Error inesperado durante la obtenci?n de datos del servicio DocumentosService para el expediente593718000029818
>   com.noaris.agis.exception.BusinessException at
>   com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil.getComunicaciones(DocumentosServiceUtil.java:65)at
>   com.noaris.agis.screens.expedientes.DetalleExpediente_DocumentacionVM$DocumentosServiceThread.run(DetalleExpediente_DocumentacionVM.java:1028)

```
The certificates in the preproduction machines are well installed in the java carcets. Therefore the exception unable to find valid certification path to requested target, we can not understand why it is launched.

On the other hand, two warn "UNKNOWN" appear when it enters the DocumentService class. We think that maybe this may be because when we enter the wsdl we need to get credit in advance. In this case we do not know how to insert the username and password before calling the wsdl ... if necessary.
```

We have been stuck with this problem for weeks. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Greetings and thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is highlighted in this line:
SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

On your local Windows machine, you have built-in access to the key store.  But, from a remote machine, this certificate isn't visible.

To quickly see if this is true, put a 'hello.html' page on that site, and check in any browser what certificate is returned by 'https://yourwebpage.com/hello.html'.  Until that returns your expected cert, your code won't work.

HTH, Jim